# What are the ways to clear out Xcode linker settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, cocos2d-x-3.0, soomla

**My question:**

Is it possible for Xcode (7.2.1) to erroneously retain instructions to link a framework that is no longer anywhere in the project? If so, how can this be solved?

**My problem:**

I'm trying to compile an iOS project using Cocos2d-x v3.10 and the latest versions of the Soomla modules, particularly Soomla Profile. Other Soomla modules worked before I implemented Profile, but as soon as I add `-lSoomlaiOSProfileFacebook` as a linker flag, I get a compile-time error:

```
ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm thoroughly confused by this, as `FBSDKCoreKit` is a framework used in Facebook's iOS SDK version 4.0 and above, and Soomla Profile is only configured to use 3.0 (and therefore shouldn't be asking for `FBSDKCoreKit`). I have the `FacebookSDK` framework version 3.23.3 integrated into the project. There is nothing in my project that should be referencing or asking for `FBSDKCoreKit`.

My only possible explanation is that at one time I did have `FBSDKCoreKit` in my project before I understood that Soomla wouldn't work with it, and I successfully triggered a couple actions that were registered in the Facebook Developer portal (this was NOT done using Soomla commands, and this was done before the `-lSoomlaiOSProfileFacebook` library was linked). I feel like Xcode may be hanging on to some memory of `FBSDKCoreKit` for some reason, even though the framework has been completely removed along with all references.

To sum: Soomla should be looking for `FacebookSDK`, not `FBSDKCoreKit`.

**Things I have tried:**

- Erasing the entire project and cloning a git commit from before implementation of Facebook was ever attempted
- Erasing Xcode derived data (from both within Xcode and directly from Finder)
- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the Facebook SDK and reinstalling
- Deleting all Soomla modules and reinstalling by 1) removing references to Soomla projects and libraries from the project, 2) deleting Soomla modules from Cocos2d-x directory and replacing them with freshly downloaded versions (this includes the library referenced by `-lSoomlaiOSProfileFacebook`), re-adding them to the project (both Xcode project files and static libraries)

All of these have been tried multiple times, and I have at least once done every step before a compile attempt.

I am convinced there is nothing in the project that should be asking for `FBSDKCoreKit`, which makes me wonder if this is an Xcode issue. Are there any next steps for a problem of this nature?

**References**

- [Paste of the compile error output](http://pastebin.com/0cMWWYrK)
- [Post on Soomla forums regarding this issue](https://answers.soom.la/t/lsoomlaiosprofilefacebook-links-to-wrong-sdk/4804). This post also includes confirmation that the `FBSDKCoreKit` library isn't in my project.

I will happily include any more information you all feel is relevant. Any feedback or troubleshooting tips would be happily appreciated.

Comment: Try opening up the PBXProj file inside of the Xcode project and search for your phantom frameworks. I've seen something similar where Xcode 6 was fixing a missing framework path for me but this was corrected in Xcode 7, causing my project to fail to build.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `FBSDKCoreKit` in the raw project file (project.pbxproj)?  I've had issues before where Xcode didn't clean up the project correctly when making changes via the UI, but the evidence is still there in the raw project.

Comment: Thank you both, @Moshe and @fullofsquirrels. Unfortunately, I checked the .pbxproj file and there are no references to `FBSDKCoreKit`, only `FacebookSDK`. Great idea that I hadn't thought of, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occam's Razor led me to `grep` all the static libraries provided with the Soomla Profile project. Turns out that starting with 1.4.0 (it's currently on 1.8.1) the provided binaries are querying the wrong SDK after all. I've opened a PR but keeping this question up because of the fantastic responses that taught me about checking the .pbxproj files.